# Socrates more than Enlightened?

Tags: discussion, badges

Jon Skeet recently earned the **Enlightened** badge.The next one is Socrates.

How can *Socrates* be more than "Enlightened"?

What is the criteria of which this is decided?

P.S I am not talking about badges based on the users' activity, but more of the naming convention!

[image: this]

Comment: This question is better on [english.SE].

Comment: I see you've [just deleted a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366980/dealing-with-ungratefulness). It was a good question, so I recommend you undelete it. Don't worry about the downvotes - they just signify disagreement here. Doesn't mean it shouldn't be discussed. (Pro tip: I recommend you keep the edits though - they were helpful).

Comment: @halfer I just un deleted it however I don't know why so much hate?

Comment: There was no "hate" at all - that's just an incorrect perception. People feel free to disagree quite frankly on Meta, but then downvotes don't affect your score here, so it doesn't matter. Thanks for undeleting.

Comment: (_Meta meta_: the use of the word "hate" to describe disagreement is popular these days, perhaps in order to paint people who disagree as a "hater" (i.e. an unreasonable extremist, like a racist). However, it is OK to disagree, anywhere, online or offline. It matters how people do it, of course, and if someone is rude in their disagreement then you might stop listening to them. That's OK too. As other recent disagreements on _Meta_ have shown, we all need to find the tools to _try_ listening to the other side, rather than finding ways to ostracise them).

Comment: @halfer how can I delete this question

Comment: This one, about badges? If you cannot delete it in the same way as the other one, it may be because it has an answer. But in general I would recommend against deleting this one too - someone gave you a good answer below, and it doesn't seem fair to make that a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Socratic** has nothing to do with **Enlightened**. *Socratic* is the gold version of *Curious* and *Inquisitive*, while *Enlightened* is a single badge on its own.

One is free to choose which badge to track next in their [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current). You just click on the gear next to the text "Next badge", and a list of trackable badges will show up. If one tracked badge is awarded, the system will automatically choose the badge with the highest progress from the rest.

Meanwhile, there are some badges that cannot be tracked here. For example, Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer, Popular/Notable/Famous Question, etc. They will show at the "Newest" place after you are awarded, but they do not affect your tracking badge.

The two things mentioned above makes it possible that the names for "Newest" and "Next badge" are irrelevant.

[image]

Comment: what makes a person earn the Enlightened badge

Comment: @D.'s Don't you look it up in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)?