# Can we allow editors to mark the correct answer on behalf of an ungrateful question author?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer

I see a lot of people who create a profile with only **one reputation**, ask a question and they don't accept the answer. This has nothing to do with junior developers, they are of all levels, and they keep asking questions till they aren't allowed any more!

Shouldn't Stack Overflow grant **editors** the right to mark somebody's answer, if the person asking it has more than one day that hasn't opened or cared to reply?

In some communities it can be discussed, not all deal with code and science but it's hard for me to believe that someone **asks 15 questions** each question has at least **4 answers** and he/she doesn't even care to mark not even one as right!

It takes time and effort to answer a questions, isn't it time to do so?

Comment: I don't think allowing anyone else to make that decision for the OP would be a good idea. But flagging the question in some way or another automatically after a while might be a start; something like a "soft accept" along the lines of "the OP hasn't officially said so, but this question has a bunch of answers already and this one here is pretty highly voted…"

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate but we'll never be able to judge which answer helped the OP most. If down votes and close votes make people feel berated I guess deciding for them what helped them most is ultimate offensive. Let's not go there.

Comment: We don't care so much about this because the site's objective is to build a library of knowledge for many future readers, not just help one person. In the grand scheme of things, community upvotes are the *real* reward for good content. The accept check mark is just icing on the cake.

Comment: There are signals that both the importance and function of the accept vote are open for some change.

Comment: Interestingly, I recently discovered that the Discourse discussion platform allows privileged users to mark the correct answer, without any input from the question author. So, while I am not sure it is appropriate for SO, there is a precedent for this proposal.

Comment: @Pekka웃: wouldn't your view naturally lead to the conclusion that a privileged user ought to be able to accept an answer (e.g. in the case of a question being abandoned without acceptance)?

Comment: @halfer yeah, I wouldn't mind that happening and don't understand the pushback the suggestion has been getting whenever it came up. It's just not something to get upset about for individual users. I do agree the UI makes the check mark look like a much bigger deal than it supposedly is

Comment: Closely related: [Can moderators make an answer accepted to close the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672) *(and linked questions)*

Comment: @Pekka웃: I suppose it depends on what we think the acceptance mark means. It currently means "what was most helpful for the question author", but I wonder if it is popularly interpreted as a more general "which one is correct [for any user]".

Comment: It could also be that the OP has not accepted any of the answers -- they should not be compelled to mark an answer as accepted if it didn't actually help them.  The accepted mark means what answer helped the OP the most, so it likewise makes no sense for anyone other than the OP to accept the answer.

Comment: If other users want the answer to be recognized, they already have a tool for that: the upvote button.

Comment: @DavyM I have specified in the question under what circumstances

Comment: @D.'s These circumstances hinge on your assumption that the Asker hasn't "cared to reply." I'm saying there are valid reasons not to care to reply. A circumstance where it might be worthwhile doing this could be if the asker explicitly comments "Thanks this helped me so much," in which case a cool feature would be erase the comment and replace it with the green check after a day. But if the asker hasn't indicated that any specific answer has helped them, even if there are 15 questions all with answers, then nobody else can determine for the OP which to accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two questions here, really:

- Can privileged users accept on behalf of a question author?
- How to deal with question authors who accept zero or a very small proportion of answers they receive?

In relation to the second one: we used to have a system called "acceptance rate", which appeared in people's profile cards, and indicated how good they were at accepting answers (accepted as a percentage of total). However, it was withdrawn on the basis that readers were taking people to task too aggressively for not having a high acceptance rate - and we weren't sure if that was an optimal outcome anyway. Some questions attract unacceptable answers.

However, people still can look at an author's question history, and if they notice there are zero or few "solid green" questions, it means that either:

- the author does not know there is an acceptance system
- the author does not know how to use the acceptance system
- the author does not see the value in the acceptance system
- the author cannot be bothered to use the acceptance system

This is mostly an educational issue, and we even have boilerplate comment strings that can be posted in these cases that link to the relevant Help page (see elsewhere on Meta). If you are *sure* that a user is wilfully not using the system, you can downvote their question, since their behaviour is "not useful". However, you can only do that once per user (we don't serial vote here) so you may find a softer approach works better.

Personally, I have found that posting friendly advice often works where the user comes back, and in the cases where the user doesn't come back, there's not much we can do about that.

If you find this phenomena frustrating, you could prefer questions that come from 100+ rep users if you like. That score might indicate they are more committed to using the platform again, increasing your chance of an upvote or an accept.