# Bring back acceptance rate

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, accepted-answer

I see some users no matter how much you help them, they still neither **Upvote** or **Accept any answer**, and this has got to stop!  We need to know their *acceptance rate*.

Comment: What will you do with that figure exactly?

Comment: Why does this "got" to stop? The site hasn't had that in a while and we didn't go down in flames.... so "got" is probably an exaggeration. Can you explain what benefit you see from this?

Comment: @Clive I would do what I do now,tell them to reward people who have helped them,from some I have gotten good responses and have helped them even further their actual question from others no reply at all!

Comment: @Eminem you say "got" as if it was an absolute necessity. I feel like this is an exaggeration in and of itself, since this is in no way, shape or form a necessity...

Comment: Far too many complaints about it.  We can't have nice things when users complain.

Comment: @Patrice its an exaggeration ,I okay with helping sb who needs recomandation about a book or how to do smth,but not sb who doesnt care

Comment: @Eminem then... maybe Stack isn't for you? Because here you are basically saying you are ok answering off topic questions, but not okay with answering questions for future visitors... which is the main thing we do :/. A good answer that doesn't get the accept will, in the long run, get at least 2 upvotes, which give more than the accept... so I don't see why there should be so much focus there

Comment: Those comments are just noise, I can’t think of a reason we’d want to encourage them.

Comment: @Patrice You're right, we shouldn't just focus on acceptance, so we should also add an "upvote rate" to all user's user card that shows the percentage of posts that they've viewed that they've upvoted, to ensure that people are upvoting all of the posts that they read, in addition to ensuring that people asking questions are accepting answers.

Comment: @Patrice offtopic is another thing and encouraging beginners is another thing.I don't see how that is offtopic

Comment: @Eminem Then I suggest you spend some time looking through the on topic sections of the help center.

Comment: Strive to make your answers insightful to future visitors. That's how you get upvotes in the long run. Helping question posters is really just corollary on SO. And think of accept marks as decoration.

Comment: @Eminem you say yourself, you don't care to answer sb who needs recommandation about a book. That is off-topic on Stack.

Comment: @Servy oh boy.... I think most of us would have a pretty bad (good?) rate there

Comment: @Patrice According to Stack new Policy,new users and begginers  dont find it very helpful so they should be encouraged

Comment: @Eminem we can encourage, without going against something who is off-topic for the site. I can be welcoming to people in my house, while still asking them to not hit my pet for no reason. Same thing here. You can be welcoming and helping. You don't have to answer everything, including off-topic questions.

Comment: @Patrice how marking a new users answer as duplicate encourage them??????????

Comment: @Eminem that is a **completely** separate topic. Mind sticking to the acceptance rate? I don't feel like going off tangents

Comment: Give me a break...I am always ready to help sb who at least says thank you

Comment: *Member for 5 months*... who told you about acceptance rate? Nah, that's best left in the past.

Comment: @Eminem I take it you don't want to talk about it then. Have a good one!

Comment: @BilltheLizard https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366986/9025311

Comment: For reasons why this was removed, see ["Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) . It led to fights, revenge downvoting, people accepting answer they knew were incorrect just to keep that number up, and so on. All indications are that this would happen again.

Comment: Already available: https://stackapps.com/questions/4226/user-accept-rate

Comment: Accept rate or not accept rate, if you're expecting upvotes and accepts from OPs, I can foresee lots of suffering in your near future :p

Comment: If you like answering questions from new users, then I assume you forgot that most of them **can't upvote** since they need [15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to do it?

Comment: @AndrewT. that's not an excuse not to help,they can always mark the answer,ungrateful people are

Answer (score 29):

No.

Pretty much anything you would do based on knowing a user's acceptance rate would be either counter-productive or unproductive. Choosing not to answer a question from a low-acceptance rate user? You're making the site worse by not providing useful information, not because of a low-quality question but because of the user. Making a comment about their accept rate? That's adding noise; it won't improve the quality of any questions.

Comment: The question is, will this answer be accepted?

Comment: @Chris_Rands That is the kind of Meta irony we're all here for!

Comment: Nope,it will not!the real answer is rene comment

Comment: So @Eminem according to your own heuristics Nicol shouldn't have answered.... Interesting. And btw, they both are valid. Nicol's answer (they won't bring it back) is correct. Rene gave you a userscript that does it, sure. But Stack won't bring it back...

Comment: @Patrice No,but you can hate as much as you want

Comment: @Eminem You can also choose to respect the community's general consensus. From what one can see in your comments in this question, you have a very different perspective of what this site is, and that is worrying, to say the least.

Comment: @Eminem hate? Did I say hate, or use any kind of language that showed hate or anger? Might you just be looking for an argument? I am just explaining how it is. Stack has taken acceptance rate and won't bring it back. That is the real answer. There is an app that lets you get it back. Doesn't change that the answer to your question 'bring back acceptance rate' is no. You can deny that all you want. Doesn't change the facts.